# Using sqlite3 in -html mode from ruby

Tags: ruby, sqlite

I'm trying to figure out how can i use in Ruby, the equivalent of:

```
sqlite3 -html $database_location $query >> $output
```

From man sqlite3 you have:

```
 .mode MODE ?TABLE?     Set output mode where MODE is one of:
                            csv      Comma-separated values
                            column   Left-aligned columns.  (See .width)
                            html     HTML <table> code
                            insert   SQL insert statements for TABLE
                            line     One value per line
                            list     Values delimited by .separator string
                            tabs     Tab-separated values
                            tcl      TCL list elements
```

Which is something i cant find in http://sqlite-ruby.rubyforge.org/sqlite3/classes/SQLite3/Database.html

Any advice?

Comment: What is your goal? It's easy to tell sqlite3 to output the data and capture it using backticks, but wanting to do so is questionable. Typically we'd use something like Sinatra and HAML rather than rely on the DBM to generate output.

Comment: My goal is to query an sqlite3 db, append to file and send via email, i'm not using this within Rails or web application, the content will be surrounded by html content that will be rendered in the email. so i have; <table>{result of queries here}</table> this is extreamly comfortable for me as it inserts the <tr><th></th><tr> and saves me loads of work, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using backticks?:

```
output = `sqlite3 -html #{ database_location } #{ query }`
```

This isn't how we'd normally use a database though. Instead, for more control and because you're going to be nearly there, consider using [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/), [Haml](http://haml.info/) and maybe even [Sequel](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel).

Check out their README files. They'll make your life easier and will provide a lot more flexibility.

---

If your goal is to automate sending an email, then the fast path would be to pipe the HTML output of SQLite to the mail app. I'd do something like:

```
`sqlite3 -html #{ database_location } #{ query } | mail -s "DB info" userid@email.com`
```

Comment: My goal is to query an sqlite3 db, append to file and send via email, i'm not using this within Rails or web application, the content will be surrounded by html content that will be rendered in the email. so i have; <table>{result of queries here}</table> this is extreamly comfortable for me as it inserts the <tr><th></th><tr> and saves me loads of work, thx